# Collection of Enums in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I work with Vue.js, so the question concerns Vue components specifically. There are instances in my code where I would like to compare something to an enum. This works fine in the script portion of the .vue file, but not the html portion, meaning this:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        {{MyEnum.EnumMemberOne}}
    </v-app>
</template>
```

would cause an error: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "MyEnum" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. ...`

So I have to do this in my script to have access to my enum:

```
import {MyEnum} from "@/types";

@Component({
    components: {}
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    myEnum = MyEnum;
}
```

Then I can simply refer to my enum using `myEnum` within the html portion. Not too annoying, but my problem is that I'll have many enums, and I don't want to have to manually create variables for each enum in each component.

So what I would like to do is basically have a collection of enums, so that no matter how many enums I have and no matter which enums I actually want to use in each component, they're all available.

So in my types.ts file (where I define all interfaces and enums), I'd like to do something like this:

```
export enum MyEnum1 {
    EnumMemberOne,
    EnumMemberTwo,
}

export enum MyEnum2 {
    EnumMemberOne,
    EnumMemberTwo,
}

export interface EnumCollection {
    MyEnum1: MyEnum1;
    MyEnum2: MyEnum2;
}
```

So that in every component, I can just do this: `enumCollection = EnumCollection;`

And use it in the html portion like this:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        {{enumCollection.MyEnum1.EnumMemberOne}}
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Is that possible? If not, is there a better way to "collect" all possible enums in one place?

Comment: I'm not versed in Vue.js, but I wonder if assigning your import an alias would solve this problem? `import {MyEnum as myEnum} from "@/types";`

Comment: @Zze Maybe that would work (I'll try it when I'm back home), but that would still require me to import every single enum, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar but I wanted all enums in their own file so there is a Constants file that bundles them all into one:

in Constants.ts:

```
export * from '@/app/constants/MyEnum1';
export * from '@/app/constants/MyEnum2';
export * from '@/app/constants/MyEnum3';
```

in MyEnum1.ts, MyEnum2.ts, etc:

```
export enum MyEnum1 {
    EnumMemberOne,
    EnumMemberTwo,
}
```

somewhere in my main file:

```
import { createApp }       from 'vue';
import { App as VueApp }   from 'vue';
import * as constants      from '@/app/constants/Constants';

// ....

const vueApp:VueApp<Element> = createApp(AppVue);

vueApp.config.globalProperties.const = constants;

// ....
```

Now you can use `const.xxx` in any template anywhere in your app:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        {{const.MyEnum1.EnumMemberOne}}
    </v-app>
</template>
```

PS: The above code is from a Vue3 project, but something similar should also work for Vue2